# iOS app not sending any request, no traffic at all?

Tags: ios, debugging

I am trying to inspect the traffic of this iOS app: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wolfy/id1489243120

However, I can't see ANYTHING being sent from it, no HTTP or WS traffic.

Why? Any reason this could be happening? I always has been able to successfully debug other apps, but this one won't work.

I tried using both Charles Proxy iOS and Windows app, and also Burp Suite, same results: nothing.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

have you figured out how to debug on your iOS device? If not, you might try [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/) to see if it works. [This blog](https://medium.com/@lucyreview/how-i-use-proxyman-to-see-http-requests-responses-on-my-iphone-8e1f3868d343) will show you details for configuration. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. However, I haven't got any Mac so I can't use Proxyman. I don't think the debugger I use is the problem as I tried with Fiddler, Charles and Burp, simply no requests are showing up. Thank you.